# Python NameError: global name not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, global, nameerror

I am trying to use a function within another function and its giving error. I am using class as a structure. I tried initializing chunk to zero and it didnt work.  Also chunk is a byte

```
Chunk = bytearray(b'\x00') # is it a good idea to use this or any other options?

class Prog:
    PROGRAMMING_FLAG       = False
    SET_ADD_FLAG           = False
    DATA_FLAG              = False
    ADD_COMMAND_FLAG       = False
    ERASE_FLAG             = False
    ATTEMPT                = 1

def prog_flash(Chunk):

try:
    Prog.DATA_BUFFER = []
    Prog.ADD_COMMAND_FLAG = True
    Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(0x02))
    No_Of_Bytes = Chunk * 64
    for index in range(0,64):
        Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(DataBuffer[No_Of_Bytes+index]))
    Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(Calculate_Checksum(Prog.DATA_BUFFER[1:Prog.DATA_BUFFER.__len__()])))
    Prog.DATA_FLAG = True
    return Prog.DATA_BUFFER

except Exception, e:
    print("Error")
    pass

def other_fn():
   prog_flash(Chunk)
```

**Error:**

> NameError: global name 'Chunk' is not defined

Comment: Of course `Chunk` is never defined, you never assign to it. What are you trying to pass to `prog_flash`

Comment: There are way too many problems with this code and you haven't shared the actual error

Comment: What value are you trying to pass to `pring_flash()`? `Chunk` is a variable name *inside the `prog_flash()` function*, not outside.

Comment: chunk is a some size of data in bytes. hex 0x02 is a command to write to it to make raspberry pi aware of command to start flashing. How should I define Chunk ? Tried initializing and using but it gave the same error

Comment: This shouldn't have even finished running with a Name Error; there should be a Syntax Error well before that becomes a problem.

Comment: i defined chunk as bytearray(b'x00')

Answer (score 0):

DataBuffer is not defined, also Calculate_Checksum is not definied,

the structure should be like

```
Chunk = bytearray(b'\x00') # is it a good idea to use this or any other options?

class Prog:
    PROGRAMMING_FLAG       = False
    SET_ADD_FLAG           = False
    DATA_FLAG              = False
    ADD_COMMAND_FLAG       = False
    ERASE_FLAG             = False
    ATTEMPT                = 1

def prog_flash(Chunk):

    try:
        Prog.DATA_BUFFER = []
        Prog.ADD_COMMAND_FLAG = True
        Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(0x02))
        No_Of_Bytes = Chunk * 64
        for index in range(0,64):
            Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(DataBuffer[No_Of_Bytes+index]))
        Prog.DATA_BUFFER.append(hex(Calculate_Checksum(Prog.DATA_BUFFER[1:Prog.DATA_BUFFER.__len__()])))
        Prog.DATA_FLAG = True
        return Prog.DATA_BUFFER
    except Exception, e:
        # handle Expection
        print "There was an error: %s" %(e)
        pass


def other_fn():
    prog_flash(Chunk)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    other_fn()
```